# Struts2 json plugin not working

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

Following is the jsp wherein i have a struts2 jquery plugin select tag that loads its values asynchronously from an action using json:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<s:form action="#" theme="css_xhtml" cssClass="form1small" name="reportgenerationform">
    <div class="searchHeadersmall">Generate Report</div>
    <div id="searchForm1"> 
            <s:url id="remoteurl" action="providerList"/> 
            <sj:select 
                href="%{remoteurl}" 
                id="echo" 
                name="echo" 
                list="proList" 
                emptyOption="true" 
                headerKey="-1" 
                headerValue="Select"
            />
     </div
</s:form>
```

Struts.xml is as follows:

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<package name="package2" extends="struts-default,json-default">
<action name="providerList" class="com.view.AdminAction">
            <result name="success" type="json" >

            </result>
        </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Action class AdminAction is as follows:

```
public class AdminAction extends ActionSupport{    

    private List<String> proList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getProList() {
        return proList;
    }
    public void setProList(List<String> proList) {
        this.proList = proList;
    }
    public String execute() {
        proList.add("ABC");
        proList.add("DEF");
        proList.add("agC");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public String getJSON(){
        return execute();
    }
}
```

When i run this code, my select tag is not getting populated with the values i have set in my action class. Am i missing anything in it. I explored the links available on SO and also struts2 json showcase etc. Any other links and help is welcome. Thanks in advance..

Also i get this exception when i run the code:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/xwork/StringUtils
at org.apache.struts2.json.SerializationParams.<init>(SerializationParams.java:57)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.writeToResponse(JSONResult.java:214)
at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:204)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:371)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:275)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:239)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:161)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:563)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty common occurrence on Struts2. Facing the same issue :( Found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I read it correctly, you are missing dependencies. A quick google gave tons of solutions :

[Just Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+org%2Fapache%2Fcommons%2Flang%2Fxwork%2FStringUtils&oq=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%3A+org%2Fapache%2Fcommons%2Flang%2Fxwork%2FStringUtils&aqs=chrome..69i57.111j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: i have already added the struts2 json plugin  jar.. But still i get this. Also i am new to struts and json. I am working on my first app only.